# ANDROID Instantiate a Fragment Inside a PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, popupwindow

I have an Android application with a fragment used in multiple places in our app to collect address information. I have the fragment inside FragmentContainerView in the layouts and I access the fragment like this

```
fragAddress = (FragAddressEntry) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_address_form);
```

Now I have reason to create a PopupWindow where I want to collect address information and so I want to use the existing FragAddressEntry form.

How do I instantiate the FragAddressEntry from inside the PopupWindow since there is no getChildFragmentManager?

I can't convert the FragAddressEntry to a DialogFragment because that is not how the fragment is being used elsewhere.

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating a fragment with fragmentManager would require a container that has to be a part of the activity or fragment, which is not the case with PopUpWindow instead what you should do is use a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#show%28android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by changing my fragment to a custom UI component that extends a FrameLayout. This way I was able to use the address entry control as I had been in other layouts and use it in the PopupWindow without needing to change it to a DialogFragment.